# Python peewee sqlite database open in phpmyadmin?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

I started using Peewee for a project to store some information, and I am wondering if there is a way to import the local database into phpmyadmin to be able to better view and interact with the stored data. I created my db like so:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('trains.db')

class Train(Model):
    id = AutoField()
    origin = CharField()
    destination = CharField()
    due = TimeField()
    delay = IntegerField()
    est = TimeField()
    cancelled = BooleanField()
    day = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

db.connect()
db.create_tables([Train])

train = Train(origin="LNC", destination="Sheffield", due="17:49", delay=0, est="17:49", cancelled=False,day="monday")
success = train.save()
print(success)


db.close()
```

This creates a `.db` file which is not importable to phpmyadmin (I have XAMPP 3.2.4). I came across to SQLite->MySQL converters but they seem to be out of date and I'm not sure if I should just not even use SQLite, as I will have to look at the database in some nicer, visual form.

Comment: how many databases , tables , rows and columns we are talking ?

Comment: can't you use database editor like [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) or [SQLiteBrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to see database ? There should be even extenison for Firefox to work with SQLite. Probably should be extension also for Chrome.

Comment: @furas wow I never came  across this, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: There's also https://github.com/coleifer/sqlite-web

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `phpmyadmin` you can use database editor like [SQLiteBrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

[image]

---

[DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) can works with different databases so you can use it at the same time with `SQLite` and `MySQL`. It has many functions but I don't rembere if it can transfer data from one type of database to another.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

There are even extensions for web browser Firefox like [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager-webext/).

Chrome should have similar extensions.

BTW: Firefox and Chrome keep some informations (ie. bookmarks) in SQLite files.

---

Long time ago I was using also [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) but it can't work with SQLite.